# Not able to delete multiple rows from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following code. `Data` is datable

```
 DataRow[] rows;
  rows = data.Select("meta_key = '_edit_lock'");
 rows = data.Select("meta_key = 'resume_path'");
 foreach (DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
data.AcceptChanges();
```

I can only delete resume_path row from datatable and can't delete _edit_lock.

Comment: That's because you have overwritten the rows variable.

Comment: At the time I writing both the one answer and this ccmment are correct but I think this comment exposes the more general principle to learn. You should never modify the collection you are iterating over. It'll often throw exceptions but even when it doesn't it'll almost certainly lead to bugs unless you are very careful.

Instead either create a copy, or do two passes one to find the indexes of the rows/items you want to delete and the second in a loop over those indexes deleting those indexes IN REVERSE ORDER from the source list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select filter should include both conditions, like in the code below.

```
DataRow[] rows;
rows = data.Select("meta_key = '_edit_lock' OR meta_key = 'resume_path'");
foreach (DataRow r in rows) {
    r.Delete();
}
data.AcceptChanges();
```

Select filter could also be expressed as

```
"meta_key IN ('_edit_lock', 'resume_path')"
```